# Shorten part of a component (basically cut out a piece)

Tags: sketchup

I build my desk in Sketchup, but for some reason it turned out twenty centimeters too long. So I want to shorten it but I can't figure out how to do this. I basically need to cut out two parts of ten centimeter without changing anything else, see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icCNq.jpg) for clarification. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I got it. The "move" command does what I need (assuming I selected the right faces to move).